# Xpath Query help for xml

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui

I'm very new to the SOAPUI, XML & writing XPath queries. I have XML output from a REST API using SOAP UI. Now I've to create an XPath assertion to verify whether there is a Red Hat Image that is currently running, which can be found using operatingSystem id & state. But I'm not able to assertion in the SOAPUI on the output.

Do you've any suggestions for it ?

It seems like there are different namespaces and one of the url doesn't have a namespace declared in XML `xmlns="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/server"`

XML is provided below:

```
<ServersWithState pageNumber="1" pageCount="2" totalCount="2" pageSize="250" 
  xmlns:ns16="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/storage" 
  xmlns="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/server" 
  xmlns:ns14="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/support" 
  xmlns:ns15="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/multigeo" 
  xmlns:ns9="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/admin" 
  xmlns:ns5="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/vip" 
  xmlns:ns12="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/serverbootstrap" 
  xmlns:ns13="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/backup" 
  xmlns:ns6="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/general" 
  xmlns:ns7="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/datacenter" 
  xmlns:ns10="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/whitelabel" 
  xmlns:ns8="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/manualimport" 
  xmlns:ns11="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/reset" 
  xmlns:ns2="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/directory" 
  xmlns:ns4="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/network" 
  xmlns:ns3="http://testlab.example.net/schemas/organization">
   <serverWithState id="d6fb8348-97ff-4169-a4f8-33ac12ecf6ff" location="Home_LAB">
      <name>test_server_windows</name>
      <description/>
      <operatingSystem id="WIN2008S32" displayName="WIN2008S/32" type="WINDOWS"/>
      <cpuCount>2</cpuCount>
      <memoryMb>4096</memoryMb>
      <disk id="4ca8b248-573d-4210-819c-66c114ecea01" scsiId="0" sizeGb="32" speed="STANDARD" state="NORMAL"/>
      <sourceImageId>fbf3ad74-2b69-49c8-9a37-f963b3102d2c</sourceImageId>
      <networkId>9906ddd8-45aa-11e0-b7ea-0030487e0302</networkId>
      <machineName>10-157-116-11</machineName>
      <privateIp>10.157.116.11</privateIp>
      <created>2014-09-25T17:24:52.000Z</created>
      <isDeployed>true</isDeployed>
      <isStarted>true</isStarted>
      <state>NORMAL</state>
      <machineStatus name="vmwareToolsVersionStatus">
         <value>NEED_UPGRADE</value>
      </machineStatus>
      <machineStatus name="vmwareToolsRunningStatus">
         <value>RUNNING</value>
      </machineStatus>
      <machineStatus name="vmwareToolsApiVersion">
         <value>7303</value>
      </machineStatus>
   </serverWithState>
   <serverWithState id="ab271ab1-7daa-443b-bb21-a62e27a7b207" location="Home_LAB">
      <name>test_server_linux</name>
      <description/>
      <operatingSystem id="REDHAT564" displayName="REDHAT5/64" type="UNIX"/>
      <cpuCount>1</cpuCount>
      <memoryMb>2048</memoryMb>
      <disk id="41516cdb-1010-44bd-ba6e-a00bd2340974" scsiId="0" sizeGb="10" speed="STANDARD" state="NORMAL"/>
      <sourceImageId>0d6fdc8c-7529-4fb8-9028-8f133c7de2ae</sourceImageId>
      <networkId>9906ddd8-45aa-11e0-b7ea-0030487e0302</networkId>
      <machineName>10-157-116-12</machineName>
      <privateIp>10.157.116.12</privateIp>
      <created>2014-09-25T17:25:39.000Z</created>
      <isDeployed>false</isDeployed>
      <isStarted>false</isStarted>
      <state>FAILED_ADD</state>
      <status>
         <action>DEPLOY_SERVER</action>
         <requestTime>2014-09-25T17:25:39.000Z</requestTime>
         <userName>autotest</userName>
         <numberOfSteps>13</numberOfSteps>
         <updateTime>2014-09-25T17:38:00.000Z</updateTime>
         <step>
            <name>WAIT_FOR_CLONE_VM_TASK</name>
            <number>5</number>
            <percentComplete>91</percentComplete>
         </step>
         <failureReason>Could not complete network copy for file /vmfs/volumes/4b215b8c-44971195-4262-001cc4478f4b/T-RHEL-53-64-1-2-10-LAB0x/T-RHEL-53-64-1-2-10-LAB0x.vmdk</failureReason>
      </status>
   </serverWithState>
</ServersWithState>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the XPath assertions that you have tried to use.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response... Here are some assertions I'm trying to  use.
//operatingSystem[@id], //operatingSystem[starts-with(@id,'REDHAT')
Also, I've tried declaring the namespaces in XPATH assertion and gave xmlns:ns1=<server>
And then assertion based on //ns1:operatingSystem[@id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boolean(//*[local-name()='operatingSystem'][starts-with(@id, 'REDHAT')])` should work.  You have to use the `local-name()` function if you can't otherwise specify a namespace to use - if you want to do that in SoapUI you can do soemthing like this:

```
declare namespace ns "http://testlab.example.net/schemas/server"
boolean(//ns:operatingSystem[starts-with(@id, 'REDHAT')])
```

If you needed to capture an additional node in that (for example `state` or `isStarted`), you could do something like this:

```
declare namespace ns "http://testlab.example.net/schemas/server"
boolean(//ns:operatingSystem[starts-with(@id, 'REDHAT') and ../ns:state='NORMAL'])
```

Comment: Thanks Dan!! Appreciate your help. Any idea how to make an xpath assertion for the condition like 
Need to find the REDHAT server in above xml and check if it is running ?
Can it be done in the same statement ?

Comment: No problem - if this resolved your question, consider accepting it as the answer (the check box under the vote button rocker)

Comment: just modified my response above.
Looking for something if operatingsystem REDHAT present then is it running ?

Comment: Which node would tell you that?  `isStarted`?  `machineStatus/@vmwareToolsIsRunning`?  If it's `isStarted`, your query would have to add something like `[starts-with(@id, 'REDHAT') and ../*[local-name()='isStarted'] = 'true']`

Comment: It should be by state , if it is normal and would like to add something in this statement.
[code]declare namespace ns "http://testlab.example.net/schemas/server"
boolean(//ns:operatingSystem[starts-with(@id, 'REDHAT')])

Comment: Appreciate your help valuable help!! Thanks Dan.

Answer (score 0):

I am using PHP to evaluate the XPath, but you should be able to transform this into any language of your choice:

```
<?php

$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->load('in.xml');

$xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('n', 'http://testlab.example.net/schemas/server');
$result = $xpath->evaluate("boolean(
//n:serverWithState
    [starts-with(./n:operatingSystem/@id, 'REDHAT')]
    [./n:isStarted = 'true']
)");

var_dump($result);
```

This outputs `bool(false)` for your example and `bool(true)` if you change the value of `isStarted` to `true`.

Comment: Not sure I can use this.

Answer (score 0):

If an element does not have a namespace, it inherits the namespace from the parent. For SoapUI assertions - reading XML - you can use a wildcard for the namespace, like so:

```
//*:operatingSystem[starts-with(@id, 'REDHAT')]
```

EDIT:
To check the `state` in a SoapUI assertion, your XPath expression would be:

```
//*:operatingSystem[starts-with(@id, 'REDHAT')]/*:state
```

and the expected value would be:

```
NORMAL
```

Comment: Thanks SiKing for your response.. Just wondering how can  I use OperatingSystem ID for REDHAT and then under that use state to check it is NORMAL as true ?

Comment: Thanks Siking, Really Appreciate your response. But somehow it seems it is mandatory to declare the namespace in SOAPUI which was mentioned Dan. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RahulGupta No it is not.

Comment: I tried your method as well but didn't work for me .. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @RahulGupta: Try this it should work   ---    //*:serverWithState[*:operatingSystem[starts-with(@id, 'REDHAT')]]/*:state        -> if you specify * in xpath no need to declare namespace in soapUI

Answer (score 0):

@RahulGupta: Try this it should work   ---

`//*:serverWithState[*:operatingSystem[starts-with(@id, 'REDHAT')]]/*:state`

```
   -> if you specify * in xpath no need to declare namespace in soapUI
```